# How to display a SVG image in shiny

Tags: r, svg, shiny, htmltools

I would like to display in my web application an SVG image that I have hosted in the `images` folder. First I tried to display it with a tag but it didn't work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$img(src = "./images/SVG_Logo.svg", width = "99px")
)
```

Then I used the `rsvg` and `htmltools` packages:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(rsvg)

#Load SVG image
miLogo <- rsvg_svg("./images/SVG_Logo.svg", width = 99)
miLogo_html <- as.character(miLogo)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML(miLogo_html)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I couldn't get it to work either. In both cases the browser displays this:

[image: SVG Doesn't Work]

But if I replace the source path for example by: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg

[image: SVG_OK]

It works correctly

Could someone help me, please?

Best regards,
Wardiam

Comment: You should try to share error messages and/or screenshots of what you are seeing to help us understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. I had to create an images folder inside the www folder. Have you created a www folder to store your assets?

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # tags$img(src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paladinic/data/main/LINEA_black.svg", width = "99px")
  tags$img(src = "./images/logo.svg", width = "99px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claudio but it doesn't work in my case. I have a macbook Pro with Ventura 13. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: If I replace the source path for example by: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg
It works correctly but I prefer to display a local image

Comment: The way the start of path is written might need to change. I would test different options and let us know (e.g. "images/..." or "/images/..") Also.. are you seeing specific error messages?